# Minecraft vanilla crashes on world load?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

For about 2 weeks now my copy of Minecraft crashes on world load/create. The launcher starts correctly but when I click *Singleplayer* and load a world (or create one) it freezes on generating terrain and crashes.

I've tried deleting everything under the `.minecraft` folder, reinstalling java, nothing works.

Crash report (pastebin): Click [here](http://i3chvpq5c1.qjtv.e.s54.ru.wbprx.com/NjjDV225)

If it doesn't work here's the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I just don't know what went wrong :(

Time: 3/06/15 09:37 PM
Description: Updating screen events

java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:61)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:52)
    at ll$1.a(SourceFile:44)
    at ll$1.b(SourceFile:41)
    at no.c(SourceFile:10)
    at ll.a(SourceFile:121)
    at ave.a(SourceFile:1941)
    at axb.a(SourceFile:210)
    at axu.a(SourceFile:350)
    at axb.a(SourceFile:350)
    at axu.k(SourceFile:413)
    at axu.p(SourceFile:390)
    at ave.s(SourceFile:1497)
    at ave.av(SourceFile:888)
    at ave.a(SourceFile:325)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:128)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:120)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:87)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:64)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:170)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127)
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:126)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:449)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:647)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(PipeImpl.java:130)
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:83)
    ... 28 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:49)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:61)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:52)
    at ll$1.a(SourceFile:44)
    at ll$1.b(SourceFile:41)
    at no.c(SourceFile:10)
    at ll.a(SourceFile:121)
    at ave.a(SourceFile:1941)
    at axb.a(SourceFile:210)
    at axu.a(SourceFile:350)
    at axb.a(SourceFile:350)
    at axu.k(SourceFile:413)
    at axu.p(SourceFile:390)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: aya
Stacktrace:
    at ave.s(SourceFile:1497)
    at ave.av(SourceFile:888)
    at ave.a(SourceFile:325)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.6
    Operating System: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
    CPU: 2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 847 @ 1.10GHz
    Java Version: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 125741144 bytes (119 MB) / 336470016 bytes (320 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 13, tallocated: 95
    Launched Version: 1.8.6
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics GL version 3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.3517, Intel
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: ^^Yeah, we're getting a '403 Forbidden' error when we click that link. Perhaps you haven't made the paste public? You can edit your post here, paste the crash, select it, and use the brackets button "**{}**" to format it into a code section :)

Comment: Its not even pastebin

Comment: the link its proxied because pastebin is blocked on my country, it works fine for me (i use safari for windows). Anyway i'll use the "{}" button, thanks.

Comment: Can you put your java version?

Comment: According to [MC-34749](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-34749), this issue is most often caused by a broken installation of Avast! free edition, and can also be caused by McAfee anti-virus. You don't happen to be using either of these, are you?

Comment: (I'm flagging an older question as a duplicate of a newer one because the newer question has a clear, accepted answer whereas this one has primarily speculation)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your stacktrace (*The list of all the event that lead up the error*) , your Java or possibly minecraft is having an issue with your network.  It cannot access something it needs to continue.

At this point there are a few things that could cause it.
But tt is hard to narrow it down from this point because minecraft's code is obfuscated and the error report is cut off by the crash handler.

1. Troubleshooting your firewall or if you have a proxy, tinkering with that.
2. Verifying your Java is installed correctly may help also.
3. Another alternative could be that this is caused by Minecraft attempting to open the world to LAN as soon as it is created.  And this would be an issue with your router/modem not having a properly setup LAN network.
4. You have launch options that are interfering with the connection information, such as a proxy for your minecraft client.  You can disable these in the minecraft launcher if you have them set.

Comment: I tried the thing about the firewall, i permited minecraft completly.
Java its installed correctly.
My router is the same as when my minecraft worked correctly.
No launch options.

Comment: If you have access to your router, check for any firewall issues their.  Unless that is what you already meant.

Comment: That is what i already meant. But thanks anyway.

Comment: It said you were using minecraft 1.8.6 at the time of the error, have you tried to update to the latest version?

Comment: If none of these work, you can backup your old `.minecraft` in your `%appdata%` and then delete the whole folder.  Afterwards relaunch minecraft.  If for some reason any file is conflicting with your minecraft, this will fix it.

Comment: minecraft 1.8.6 its the latest version.
I tried all of those things already.

Comment: 1.8.7 is the latest but I doubt it will fix it, it is just an attempt.  But since you have tried all those you can probably narrow it down to purely a network issue.

Comment: Maybe im unlucky and im the only person in the world that has this issue, and maybe its something with my PC but my problem was froma  day to another. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

after reading your stacktrace i think you are missing some files

try to clear each and every file of minecraft not by just .minecraft by your c drive and desktop too remove each and every file of java and then reinstall 32 bit java if you are using cracked minecraft if you have puchased minecraft then use 64 bit java reinstall minecraft and try it i mean that you just refresh each and every file related to minecraft if it dont work consult your problem with mojang

Comment: How are you getting the stacktrace? And if you say remove every file with `.class` or `.java`, some people who do work with java will be affected.

Comment: I removed all the things related to minecraft and java on my PC, i uninstalled java and reistalled, i have 64 bit java for purchased minecraft, i dont know what to do.

Sorry for my ignorance, but what its the stracktrace?

Comment: @Azov The stacktrace is all the `at something.something(SourceFile:1)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used a proxy app to bypass the security on my network. I turned the app off and my problem was solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem as you and my solution was to disable the windows firewall through Services>Windows Firewall> "Stop"